# jQuery "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function" when using fadeIn();

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I am new to JS and I am writing a basic jQuery-rich webpage with fade-in/fade-out for each page in the same document (using the same div element with separate IDs). Anyway, when I try to fade in the current page, I receive the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function", I've had a search around online but couldn't find a solution.

The HTML is loaded before the script and the full jQuery library has been included in the header of the page.

The div element I am targeting has "display: none;" set in my CSS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="page_content" id="page_home">
Content removed
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>

var cp = "page_home";
var tp = document.getElementById(cp);
tp.fadeIn('slow');

</script>
```

Anyone experienced anything similar and have a solution? I'm sure it's something simple, since my code is anyway...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tp` is a plain javascript object and it does not has a function called `.fadeIn()`

Try to wrap it inside `$()` to make it a jquery object then do,

```
$(tp).fadeIn('slow');
```

or better use jquery's [`id selector`](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) to grab the element,

```
$("#page_home").fadeIn('slow');
```

Comment: Works perfectly now! Thank you, it seems so obvious now I look at it, I knew to use that when selecting an ID or Class anyway, I didn't think it was required since the variable was set to the targeted ID element already.

Comment: @user3805361 Glad to help..! and by the way, if you think that anyone of the answers here has satisfied your need then try to accept it by clicking on the tick mark present inside it.. And it is not a compulsion.. :)

Comment: Yes, I was waiting for the 10 minutes, so it would let me accept yours since it was the most detailed and you replied first.

Answer (score 3):

Because `tp` is not a jquery object, it will not have the methods related to jquery.

Use,

```
$("#page_home").fadeIn('slow');
```