# Javascript - fadein image when value is equal to something

Tags: javascript, html

I have this select option:

```
<div class="okreci_select">
        <select onchange="changeImage(this)" id="selectid">
         <option value="samsung">Samsung</option>
         <option value="apple">Apple</option>
         <option value="lg">LG</option>
         <option value="htc">HTC</option>
        </select>
</div>
```

And I have this js function:

```
function changeImage(el) {
    if (el.value == "samsung"){
      document.getElementById("IzabranUredjajSl").src = "Slike/uredjajSamsung.png";
      document.getElementById("prom_vr_kara").innerHTML = "- 5.1” / 2560x1440 ekran <br/> - 12 MP / 5 MP kamere <br/> - Octa-core / 4 GB platforma <br/> - do 32 GB memorije ";
    }
      else if(el.value == "apple"){
        document.getElementById("IzabranUredjajSl").src = "Slike/uredjajApple.png";
        document.getElementById("prom_vr_kara").innerHTML = "- 4.7” / 1334x750 ekran <br/> - 12 MP / 7 MP kamere <br/> - Quad-core / 2 GB platforma <br/> - do 32 GB memorije ";
    }
}
```

How can I use the fadein() method when the el.value is equal to something. For example, when the value is apple, I want the uredjajApple.png to fadein. I've tried:

```
document.getElementById("IzabranUredjajSl").src = "Slike/uredjajApple.png".fadein();
```

But it doesn't work. Same goes for the text (innerHTML), **how do I make them fade in when the el.value changes?**

Comment: try adding document.getElementById("prom_vr_kara").fadeIn(1000); after the other two lines of code

Comment: You mean like this: document.getElementById("prom_vr_kara").fadein(3000) = "texttext"; It doesn't work :( @JonHerbert

Comment: Well I don't think that would work because you're not setting the correct thing, If you want to change the text then you need to reference the text first.

Comment: Also if you're going to be referencing those elements a lot I would consider turning them into variables instead

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
function changeImage(el) {
    $(el).fadeIn( "slow", function() {
        if (el.value == "samsung"){
          document.getElementById("IzabranUredjajSl").src = "Slike/uredjajSamsung.png";
          document.getElementById("prom_vr_kara").innerHTML = "- 5.1” / 2560x1440 ekran <br/> - 12 MP / 5 MP kamere <br/> - Octa-core / 4 GB platforma <br/> - do 32 GB memorije ";
        }
        else if(el.value == "apple"){
            document.getElementById("IzabranUredjajSl").src = "Slike/uredjajApple.png";
            document.getElementById("prom_vr_kara").innerHTML = "- 4.7” / 1334x750 ekran <br/> - 12 MP / 7 MP kamere <br/> - Quad-core / 2 GB platforma <br/> - do 32 GB memorije ";
        }
    });
}
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/ You may need to play around with the place in which you call the fadein function, perhaps within the if/else statement, sorry don't have the time to check myself. But read the Docs and you should be good to go

**EDIT**

Reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573690/jquery-uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-when-using-fadein)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: el.fadeIn is not a function @JonHerbery. I'll look around in the docs

Comment: try now and if not add an id selector for the function as per the other question referenced

Comment: Fixed my problem by adding fadeout before the image changes, then fading in after

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my problem by adding fade out before the picture changes then fade in after the picture changes:

```
function changeImage(el) {
  if (el.value == "samsung"){
    $("#IzabranUredjajSl").fadeOut(1);
    document.getElementById("IzabranUredjajSl").src = "Slike/uredjajSamsung.png";
    $("#IzabranUredjajSl").fadeIn(1000);
    document.getElementById("prom_vr_kara").innerHTML = "- 5.1” / 2560x1440 ekran <br/> - 12 MP / 5 MP kamere <br/> - Octa-core / 4 GB platforma <br/> - do 32 GB memorije ";
    document.getElementById("prom_vr_cena").innerHTML = "- Zvezda | 70 000din <br/> - Sunce | 50 000din <br/> - Gаlаksijа | 30 000din <br/>";
  }
  else if(el.value == "apple"){
    $("#IzabranUredjajSl").fadeOut(1);
    document.getElementById("IzabranUredjajSl").src = "Slike/uredjajApple.png";
    $("#IzabranUredjajSl").fadeIn(1000);
    document.getElementById("prom_vr_kara").innerHTML = "- 4.7” / 1334x750 ekran <br/> - 12 MP / 7 MP kamere <br/> - Quad-core / 2 GB platforma <br/> - do 32 GB memorije ";
    document.getElementById("prom_vr_cena").innerHTML = "- Zvezda | 80 000din <br/> - Sunce | 60 000din <br/> - Gаlаksijа | 40 000din <br/>";
  }
```